# I need guidance in fixing pagination PHP code

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

I'm working on a piece of code that does pagination for different sorting systems. It works for *likes* (sorting system) and outputs correctly, but does not work for the sorting system of *tag*.

```
$sorting = $_GET["sorting"];
$page = $_GET["page"];

$per_page = 10;
$pages = $count_total->num_rows;
$total_pages = ceil($pages / $per_page);

if($sorting == "likes") {
    $count_total = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user='$user'");
}

if($sorting == "tag") {
    $tag_name = $_GET["tag_name"];
    $count_total = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movie_tags WHERE tag_id='$tag_name'");
}

$pages = $count_total->num_rows;
$total_pages = ceil($pages / $per_page);

$start = (($page - 1) * $per_page);


for ($number=1; $number<=$total_pages; $number++) {
    if($page == $number) {
        echo '<div class="complete_page">'.$number.'</div>';
    } else {
        $sorting = $_GET["sorting"];
        echo '<a href="?page='.$number.'&sorting='.$sorting.'"> <div class="number_page">'.$number.'</div></a>';
    }
}
```

This is an example of how I'm using pagination:

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

**NOTE**: When I echo `$pages`, both sorting systems generate values. In fact, tag has a value of `11`. Why is this value not creating the pagination system. I know this is not a problem with the pagination system because it is working for the sorting system of likes.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB I know. I'm a procrastinator and need to increase the security on my site. I'm a new developer and I'm trying to learn as much as I can...

Comment: did you pass in a `tag_name` query value in your pagination? I don't see any in the page numbers you output, so `$_GET['tag_name']` is undefined, and you're doing `... where tag_id=''`

Comment: This information is found through the URL, information I didn't include in the question. I apologize, this is what the URL might look like: `http://localhost/Drop%20Box/movies.php?page=1&sorting=tag&tag_name=1`

Answer (score 0):

To have pagination in php, Simply you have to use two things in query.

1. Offset
2. Limit

For example for having pagination the query looks like

```
Select * from table Limit 5 Offset 0
```

Make logic in php, get count of products and change these two values for pagination

Comment: This does not work. There is no problem in the pagination code or the while loop because it works for the other sorting system. I believe there is a problem with the variables. However, I'm confused because I'm getting a value of `11`